# How to find all Node Ref's which are using custom aspect property with CMIS 1.1?

Tags: alfresco

We have created custom property using custom content model. We need to fetch below information from the custom content model. We are using alfresco 4.2.2;

1. How can we find all Node Ref's which are having the `cc:productstatus` property using `CMIS 1.1`?
2. and then how to delete that property for these nodeRef's using Java.

   ```
   <namespaces> 
     <namespace uri="http://www.custom.co/model/product/1.0" prefix="cc"/> 
   </namespaces> 

   <aspects>
     <aspect name="cc:product">
       <title>Status</title>
       <parent/>
       <properties>
         <property name="cc:productstatus">
           <title>status</title>
           <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
       </properties>
     </aspect>
   </aspects>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just select from an aspect same like from a type:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cc:product as p  
WHERE 
  p.cc:productstatus is not null
```

and JOIN if you need e.g. use two aspects:

```
SELECT * 
FROM app:inlineeditable as d 
JOIN cm:titled as p on d.cmis:objectId = p.cmis:objectId 
WHERE
  d.app:editInline = true and 
  p.cm:title like 'categorysearch.get.html.404.ftl'
```

now you can use `nodeService` to [remove aspect](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.1/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#removeAspect(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName)).

Comment: hi,

Is it require join with cmis:document ?what is the difference between query you have written with one aspect name & the below query.

SELECT d.*,p.* FROM cmis:document as d join FROM cc:product as p  
 on d.cmis:objectId = p.cmis:objectId  WHERE   p.cc:productstatus is not null

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM cc:product as p;  Executed this query in CMIS Workbench and returning results but When I append Where condition then pop up error is coming  "no viable alternative at character 'd'  "

Comment: it is not required to join with other type or aspect... use Alfresco Node Browser to execute queries (cmis-alfresco): http://localhost:8080/share/page/console/admin-console/node-browser#state=panel%3Dsearch%26lang%3Dcmis-alfresco%26store%3Dworkspace%253A%252F%252FSpacesStore

Comment: but when I append Where condition to the aspect then pop up error is coming "no viable alternative at character 'd' ".why this error is coming?

Comment: What alfresco version do you use? Show your query statement, were do you execute it?

Comment: 4.2.2;SELECT * FROM cc:product as p WHERE p.cc:productstatus is not null;when i append where condition then  above error is coming.

Comment: I have Alfresco 5.2 (EA), and it is working for me, test it with Node Browser http://localhost:8080/share/page/console/admin-console/node-browser#state=panel%3Dsearch%26search%3D%26lang%3Dcmis-alfresco%26store%3Dworkspace%253A%252F%252FSpacesStore